# How to input 1000 digits of integer

Tags: c

So I am on SPOJ [ `C language` ] and working out some of the initial problems, therin it says to input a number as large as 500-1000 digits.

What I do is input the data into a character array and store each digit as a character. But now afterwards if I have to do some mathematical computations on the input, I have to consider each input as a character, then subtract 48 from it [ASCII for 0] and then digit by digit work out the problem.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest optimization would be to represent the number as a byte array, using base 256, so the number is (using ^ as exponentation):

```
N = n[0]*256^0 + n[1]*256^1 + n[2]*256^2 + ...
```

That way you use the least memory.

In real life, you could use [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), which is an open-source big-numbers library.

Comment: can you explain that a bit more? What are we doing here?

Comment: Instead of each byte being a digit from 0 to 9, each byte is a base-256 'digit' from 0-255. Do you know about number systems? Like binary, octal, hex?

Comment: and how does it takes less space than mine? With my method, I will be taking one byte for each digit. [size of char = 1byte].

Comment: Haha, u act like John Snow. The thing is, you waste *space* and time, if you want to substract anything. The concept of this answer is the one you are using but taken a level higher. Why use only [0-9] of `char` to store a digit while you can use whole byte of `unsigned char`? This way you could store large integers in base of 256, so it takes less digits than in base of 10... and it's simpler to do math when you are not biased by some arbitrary '0'. IMO the bias of 48 is the biggest problem. Just convert it upon reading. Then try to implement math to operate on your structures.

Comment: Also N is the number stored and n[i] is the i'th digit in base of 256.